# Convert point shapefile into a polygon which may have holes in the middle using R

Tags: r

I have multiple point shapefiles with 20,000 - 100,000 points and I would like to create an outline/polygon from them using R. There may be holes in the middle of the polygon which I want outlined as well. I have posted pictures of how I want this to look. I have searched a lot for an answer to this using R and haven't found one that has worked. Many other examples I see don't follow the outline as closely as I would like. The polygon that I did get to work came from ArcGIS using the aggregate points (Cartography) tool with a 10 meter distance, but I want to use R.

```
    ye <- read.csv(ye1,header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
    ye$gid <- 1
    new_names <- c("easting", "northing","lat","long","yield","moisture","swath","distance","flow","interval","agl","transect","gpstime","utmzone","rmcode","gid")
    names(ye) <- new_names
    
     ye_shp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(ye[,1:2],data = ye,proj4string = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80"))
```

This is an agricultural field with 70,000+ points.
[image]

This is what I want the polygon to look like.
[image]

Comment: Starting from an arbitrary seed focus point you could try and find the nearest neighbors and connect the dots step by step. After connecting the nearest neighbor make it your next focus point and pop the last point from the queue of points. This won't work in all cases but it could give you a first spark? https://towardsdatascience.com/k-nearest-neighbors-algorithm-with-examples-in-r-simply-explained-knn-1f2c88da405c

Comment: Are the black areas in the first image due to lots of overlapping point markers? What's all the green speckles near the edges? If it is overlapping markers then you could probably do a small circular buffer at each point and then dissolve to get something like the second image.

Comment: @Spacedman - The first image is a bunch of green dots (with a standard black outline). The is a point (dot) taken every 5 feet across this crop field so at the zoom level I took the screen shot it looks black. The green dots are just some points that must be positioned to where they actually show through, but they are the same as all the others. I will tried running the buffers on a single 24k point field and it ran for 10 minutes until I killed the program.

Comment: 24,000 small point buffers created and merged should be quicker than that - can you edit your Q to show your R code you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see... First create a patchy set of regions a bit like yours by taking a random half of the `nc` dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
library(sf)
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
reg = nc[sample(nrow(nc),nrow(nc)/2),]
reg = st_transform(reg,"EPSG:3857")
plot(reg)
```

[image]

and generate 24,000 points over it:

```
pts = st_sample(reg, 24000)
plot(pts, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Now I'll do a merged approximate 5km buffer over the union of the points:

```
 system.time({b = st_buffer(st_union(pts), dist=5000)})
#   user  system elapsed 
# 34.249   0.404  34.658
```

which takes 34 seconds on this 4 year old desktop, on a single core. The resulting polygon structure is like this:

```
 plot(b)
```

[image]

which looks like the thing you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Spacedman for the help.

I tried using `gBuffer` with on the SpatialPointsDataFrame. I initially had a user error by selecting the wrong csv columns for the coordinates. I think `gBuffer` had issues with coordinate system not using planar coordinates.

Comparing the run times, I went with @Spacedman answer. However, the `gBuffer` solution by also worked but was slower.

From @Spacedman

```
    ye <- read.csv(ye1,header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
    ye_shp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(ye[,1:2],data = ye,proj4string = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80"))
  ye_shp <- st_as_sf(ye_shp)
   system.time({b = st_buffer(st_union(ye_shp), dist=7)})

for a 24k point file
   user   system elapsed 
  28.36    0.31   28.90 

for a 70k point file
  user  system elapsed 
 276.08   14.56  292.56
```

[image]

`gBuffer` solution

```
    ye <- read.csv(ye1,header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
    ye_shp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(ye[,1:2],data = ye,proj4string = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80"))

  system.time({x <- gBuffer(ye_shp,width = 7)})

for a 24k point file
   user  system  elapsed 
  25.68    0.63   26.53 

for a 70k point file
   user  system elapsed 
 473.14   16.02  493.63
```

[image]